# Passing the value of Associative array to normal base table

Tags: oracle

Version = Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition

I have read access to the database tables.

Trying to pass the value of Associative array(**Where ComputerParts = nst_tbl(i).ComputerParts**) to normal table but no luck onthis.

can someone please help me out of this and also need to add the value to the Associative Arrays after data return from normal table.

```sql
SET Serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
    TYPE t_simple_rec IS RECORD ( ComputerParts   varchar2(100) ); 
    my_rec t_simple_rec;
    
    TYPE t_nst_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
    nst_tbl t_nst_table; 
    
    v_ComputerParts VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
       
    select 'String' || rn  
    bulk collect into nst_tbl
    from (select level rn from dual connect by level <= 5);
    
    For i in 1 .. nst_tbl.count
    Loop
--       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nst_tbl(i).ComputerParts);

        Begin
            Select ComputerParts
            INTO v_ComputerParts
            From Normal_table
            Where ComputerParts = **nst_tbl(i).ComputerParts**;
            dbms_output.put_line( ' v_ComputerParts ' || v_ComputerParts );
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            dbms_output.put_line( ' NO_DATA_FOUND '  );
        END;
    
    End Loop;

END;
/
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Code you posted *works*. What is the problem, then?

Comment: my apologies for the oversight and also for late reply. code is working fine.